# getting error in matlab to python code conversion for np.gradient

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix

I am trying to translate a piece of code from matlab to python involving gradient function for (500x500) 2D matrices.
't' and 's' are 2D matrices with some values.
'T' and 'S' are 2D matrices with zeros and np.zeros respectively.
row, col are same value integers, in my case 127.

```
for i=1:row
    for j=2:col
        T(i,j)=t(i,j-1)+gradient(t(i,j-1));
        S(i,j)=s(i,j-1)+gradient(s(i,j-1));
    end
end
```

My resultant Python code is:

```
for i in range(1, row):
    for j in range(2, col):
        T[i][j] = t[i][j - 1] + np.gradient(t[i][j - 1])
        S[i][j] = s[i][j - 1] + np.gradient(s[i][j - 1])
```

But this conversion gives the error

> in gradient
>   if max(axes) >= N or min(axes) < 0:
>   ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence. 
>   I get the error during first loop in the gradient function. 
>   What am I missing here? Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you miss an indent? on the line under `for i in...` should the `for j...` be indented or is that a typo?

Comment: no that was a typo, sorry for that. done the correction here

Comment: How are you initializing `T`, `S`? I think you should be using : `[i,j]` instead of `[i][j]`.

Comment: No, that doesn't work @Divakar

Comment: Elaborate on "doesn't work"?

Comment: I tried that now,  changing [i][j] to [i,j] in python statements. Still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

You are trying to do an `np.gradient` on a scalar value. This will always return an error. For example, try `np.gradient(2)`, which will return the same error as you have above. The `np.gradient` function requires an array input. Conversely, if you give matlab a scalar input for it's `gradient` function, it returns `0`. In your matlab code, you seem to just be adding 0 to your `t` and `s` matrices to obtain your `T` and `S` matrices.

Not sure if this will fix your specific problem but don't forget python starts with index=0, whereas matlab starts with index=1. Try:

```
for i in range(0, row):
    for j in range(1, col):
        T[i][j] = t[i][j - 1] + np.gradient(t[i][j - 1])
        S[i][j] = s[i][j - 1] + np.gradient(s[i][j - 1])
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between scaler input to gradient function in matlab and python. I changed the way it worked. Though stuck in some other thing here, if I use gradient[A], where A is a  500x500 matrix, then Matlab gives 500x500 result, whereas python gives 2x500x500 matrix. Any idea how to manage this?

Comment: Hey Aman it looks like the difference is that numpy calculates the gradients between the rows and the columns (two different arrays) whereas matlab calculates only between the columns. So the numpy equivalent would be `answer = np.gradient(matrix)`, which would give you a 2xNxN array, like you say, and the `answer[1]` would be the same as matlab's answer.